# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'type'

Tags: python, variables, type

estoy intentando hacer una suma de dos variables, de las cuales una de ella es una variable que cambia depende lo que introduce el usuario. El problema es que cuando intento sumar me da el error del titulo (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'type'). Ahora introduzco el codigo para que puedan analizarlo.

### [image: captura de pantalla del error]

```
   

    saldo_inicial = float(1000)
operacion = input("¿Que operacion desea realizar? Ingresar dinero (1), retirar dinero (2), mostrar dinero disponible (3) o salir (4) ").lower()
monto = float
retiro = float
#ingreso
if (operacion == "1" or operacion == "ingresar dinero"):
    pass 
    monto == float(input("¿Cuanto dinero desea ingresar?\n $100   $200   $500   $1000\n otro monto (ingresar monto) "))
    if monto == "100" or monto == "200" or monto == "500" or monto == "1000" or monto == "$100" or monto == "$200" or monto == "$500" or monto == "$1000":
        print(f"Su saldo actual es de ${saldo_inicial + monto}")
    else :
            print(f"Su saldo actual es de ${saldo_inicial + monto}")
#retiro
elif operacion == "2" or operacion == "retirar dinero":
    pass
    retiro == float(input("¿Cuanto dinero desea retirar?\n $100   $200   $500   $1000\n"))
    if monto == ("100" or monto == "$200" or monto == "$500" or monto == "$1000"):
        print(f"Su saldo actual es de $ {saldo_inicial - monto}")
    else :
            print(f"Su saldo actual es de ${saldo_inicial - monto}")
#mostrar
elif operacion == "3" or operacion == "mostrar dinero disponible":
    print(f"Su saldo actual es de ${saldo_inicial} ")
else:
    print("Adios")
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se ejecuta esta linea:

```
monto == float(input("¿Cuanto dinero desea ingresar?\n $100   $200   $500   $1000\n otro monto (ingresar monto) "))
```

Lo que haces es ver si monto (cuyo valor es `float`) es igual a lo que ingresó el usuario, ya que '==' prueba si una igualdad es cierta o no, y estás evaluando `float == [dato ingresado por el usuario]`, lo cual siempre dará Falso.
Supongo que lo que querías hacer era guardar lo ingresado por el usuario en la variable `monto`. Para lograr eso cambia el '==' por un '='. Asi le dices a Python que estás guardando x valor en tal variable.

Comment: perfecto Dante, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda...otra vez

Comment: De nada Joaquín c:

Comment: dante te hago una ultima consulta, ahora me da el mismo error pero en la parte de #retiro (linea 13 para abajo) a pesar de haber cambiado el '==' por el '='.

Comment: Eso se debe a que en la opción 2 le estás restando el monto al saldo_inicial. Y en ningún momento cuando eliges la opción 2 cambias el valor de monto.

Comment: La cuenta que querías hacer es saldo_inicial - retiro?

Comment: es verdad, gracias

Comment: De nada jajaja, esas cosas pasan al copiar y pegar codigo, me ha pasado!

Comment: Quizá quieras cambiar "monto" a "retiro" en este condicional `if monto == ("100" or monto == "$200" or monto == "$500" or monto == "$1000"):`

Comment: Y mover el parentesis inicial antes del primer "monto"

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores.

En dos partes usas el operador de igualdad `==` en lugar del de asignación`=`.

```
monto == float(input("¿Cuanto dinero desea ingresar?\n $100   $200   $500   $1000\n otro monto (ingresar monto) "))
```

y en

```
retiro == float(input("¿Cuanto dinero desea retirar?\n $100   $200   $500   $1000\n"))
```

donde además recibes la cantidad en la variable `retiro`, pero luego validas la variable `monto`. Entonces cambie `retiro` por `monto`.

El código revisado es

```
saldo_inicial = float(1000)
operacion = input("¿Que operacion desea realizar? Ingresar dinero (1), retirar dinero (2), mostrar dinero disponible (3) o salir (4) ").lower()
monto = float
retiro = float
#ingreso
if (operacion == "1" or operacion == "ingresar dinero"):
    monto = float(input("¿Cuanto dinero desea ingresar?\n $100   $200   $500   $1000\n otro monto (ingresar monto) "))
    if monto == "100" or monto == "200" or monto == "500" or monto == "1000" or monto == "$100" or monto == "$200" or monto == "$500" or monto == "$1000":
        print(f"Su saldo actual es de ${saldo_inicial + monto}")
    else :
            print(f"Su saldo actual es de ${saldo_inicial + monto}")
#retiro
elif operacion == "2" or operacion == "retirar dinero":
    monto = float(input("¿Cuanto dinero desea retirar?\n $100   $200   $500   $1000\n"))
    if monto == ("100" or monto == "$200" or monto == "$500" or monto == "$1000"):
        print(f"Su saldo actual es de $ {saldo_inicial - monto}")
    else :
            print(f"Su saldo actual es de ${saldo_inicial - monto}")
#mostrar
elif operacion == "3" or operacion == "mostrar dinero disponible":
    print(f"Su saldo actual es de ${saldo_inicial} ")
else:
    print("Adios")
```

Tampoco necesitas los `pass`. Estos se usan sólo cuando la sintaxis exige una instrucción pero tú no deseas hacer nada.